# Will adding an ArrayList to another then clearing it afterwards reset the new?

Tags: java, arraylist

I know the title is misleading, but it's the best I could do. Here's my situation

```
public static ArrayList<Monster> wave = new ArrayList<Monster>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Monster>> waves = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Monster>>();
...
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    while(condition){
        //Add elements to the wave ArrayList
    }
    waves.add(wave); //IMPORTANT
    wave.clear();    //LINES
}
```

So here's my question; when I add wave to the waves ArrayList is it going to create a copy of it in memory, or will it actually pass the exact wave in memory to the new ArrayList? The reason I'm asking is, that I'm afraid, that clearing the wave ArrayList after adding it might result in loss of data in the waves ArrayList

Comment: Why don't you run it and try it?

Comment: The original object will be added. So your data of waves arraylist will be lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `wave` to a new ArrayList constructor in order to deep-copy it:

```
waves.add(new ArrayList<Monster>(wave));
wave.clear();
```

If `Monster` class contains non-primitive fields, you might have to deep-copy those too.

Answer (score 2):

It will pass the original list. It will not create a copy.

If you want to create a copy, you will have to do it yourself, e.g.

```
waves.add(new ArrayList<Monster>(wave));
```

Pay attention that the values of the list (monsters) will not be copied.

Answer (score 1):

you need to understand what a reference is when you add wawe to waves you are adding the reference of it. When you clear the wave, wave in waves will be cleared as well.

Comment: This is good to know. But why is it a reference and not a copy?

Comment: Because `ArrayList<Monster>` is reference type.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass Object in Java you always pass **references**.
So the Wave Array that you've added to Waves is the exact same array you have in Wave.

When you `clear()` Wave, you've cleared the object in Waves as well, because they are **the same** object.